# Sound having lower rms values but higher loudness.What are the possible reasons?

Tags: audio, python, sound

I have some noise datas which are having lower RMS values. But don't know why they are very loud when I am normalizing and playing them. After normalizing the audio remain still low rms values. But still the sound become louder. What are the possible reasons?

Here is the script how I am reading and playing the audio.

```
    import soundfile as sf   
    import os 
    import numpy as np
    def audioread(path, norm = True, start=0, stop=None):
        path = os.path.abspath(path)
        if not os.path.exists(path):
           raise ValueError("[{}] does not exist!".format(path))
        try:
           x, sr = sf.read(path, start=start, stop=stop)
        
        except RuntimeError:  # fix for sph pcm-embedded shortened v2
        print('WARNING: Audio type not supported')

        if norm:
        rms = (x ** 2).mean() ** 0.5
        print("Rms ", rms)
        scalar = 10 ** (-25 / 20) / (rms)
        x = x * scalar
        return x, sr

    from IPython.display import Audio
    Audio(noise_audio,rate = sr)
```

What are the possible reasons for such scenarios?

Comment: where does the strange value of `scalar` come from? shouldn't that just be `1/rms`?

Comment: also, if the RMS remains unchanged as a result of the linear operation `x = x * scalar`, and it sounds louder, that is either a perceptive problem, or some other part in your playback chain is doing something to your signal that you're not showing here.

Comment: please state clearly what the RMS *before* your normalization was, and what it was after, in hard numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Signal Processing SE. As already been stated your question lacks basic and critical information. You say that the RMS is lower… lower than what? What is your “reference”? Furthermore, the scaling/normalisation of the signal shouldn’t affect the relation of loudness and RMS (if the normalised level is not very different to the non-normalised so that psychoacoustic phenomena start to strike in). Regarding the fact that the sound becomes louder after normalisation, this is normal. You increase the volume by normalising, why did you expect that the loudness will remain the same? Now reg

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are normalizing all files to and RMS of -25 dBFS, which is a reasonable thing to do.

> After normalizing the audio remain still low rms values.

After the normalization the RMS should be -25 dBFS. If it isn't something is wrong with your code (but it looks ok).

> But still the sound become louder. What are the possible reasons?

The most likely one is that the RMS was lower initially. When you normalize a file that has an RMS of -35dBFS to -25 dBFS you it add 10 dB of gain which will make it about twice as loud.

Please note that "loudness" and "RMS" are only loosely related. "Loudness" is a perceptual quantity and "RMS" is a physical one. They do track with each other provided "all other things being equal", i.e. when scaling the same file. However, it's very common when comparing different noise files that the the one with higher RMS has less perceived loudness and vice versa.